# The remote server returned an error: (413) Request Entity Too Large

Tags: wcf

I know this is a redundant question, I am getting the error while I am uploading the a file which is more than 100 KB.

> The remote server returned an error: (413) Request Entity Too Large.

I am posting the content to a WCF Service (64 bit environment). Am aware this should have been resolved with managing maxReceivedMessageSize and relevant behaviours but unfortunately its not.

Below is my configurations :-

**Client**

```
     <binding allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" closeTimeout="00:01:00" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" messageEncoding="Text" name="BasicHttpBinding_ICandidateManagementService" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:11:00" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Streamed" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647"
           maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
          <security mode="None">
          <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm=""/>
            <message algorithmSuite="Default" clientCredentialType="UserName"/>
          </security>
        </binding>

 <behavior name="CandidateBehavior">
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />
        </behavior>

<endpoint address="http://localhost:62368/CandidateManagementService.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_ICandidateManagementService" contract="MMJ.ServiceContracts.ServiceContract.ICandidateManagementService" name="BasicHttpBinding_ICandidateManagementService" behaviorConfiguration="CandidateBehavior" />
```

**Service**

```
<services>
      <service name="BasicHttpBinding_ICandidateManagementService" behaviorConfiguration="CandidateBehavior">
        <endpoint contract="MMJ.ServiceContracts.ServiceContract.ICandidateManagementService" binding="basicHttpBinding" address="" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_ICandidateManagementService"/>
      </service>
```

I have seen possibly everything available and still cant solve this issue. have also tried using below configuration, but still no change...

```
<serverRuntime uploadReadAheadSize="500000000" maxRequestEntityAllowed="500000000"/>
```

Kindly help!

**Service binding Config** (its same as client)

```
<binding allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" closeTimeout="00:01:00" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" messageEncoding="Text" name="BasicHttpBinding_ICandidateManagementService" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:11:00" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
          <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxDepth="32" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"/>
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm=""/>
            <message algorithmSuite="Default" clientCredentialType="UserName"/>
          </security>
        </binding>
```

---

To give more insight below is the fiddlers finding :-

> Request Count:   1 Bytes Sent:      85,719        (headers:697; body:85,022)
>   Bytes Received:  10,129       (headers:254; body:9,875)

Comment: I thought you also needed to set some things in IIS but don't know for sure.

Comment: I don't think so, let me know if you come across any.

Comment: I retrieved the same error on Chrome. When I switched to Firefox all issues dissapeared.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At last my problem is resolved after struggling a lot. **I had a flaw in my Service config**, which was not giving me any runtime or compile time error as it was not even recognizing the config.

My Service Config was :-

```
<services>
      <service name="BasicHttpBinding_ICandidateManagementService" behaviorConfiguration="CandidateBehavior">
        <endpoint contract="MMJ.ServiceContracts.ServiceContract.ICandidateManagementService" binding="basicHttpBinding" address="" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_ICandidateManagementService"/>
      </service>
```

I have the "Name" property which is not fully qualified name of my service, and thus the configuration I used was not even considered and thus was taking default 65KB for maxReceivedMessageSize.

I have updated it and its working like a charm.

```
<services>
  <service name="MMJ.Services.CandidateManagementService">
    <endpoint contract="MMJ.ServiceContracts.ServiceContract.ICandidateManagementService" binding="basicHttpBinding" address="" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_ICandidateManagementService"/>
  </service>
```

Also, have a look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2585256/wcf-service-name-binding-name) for more reference. I know this was a silly mistake, and thanks everyone for putting an effort to fix.

Comment: Your question was helpful for me. I had the same problem but solved just using `maxReceivedMessageSize="2000000"`.

Answer (score 1):

You're posting the data to the server, so updating the client settings won't help. The client is not the one receiving the large message, the server is.

Comment: I agree... i already have updated the server configs. Its still not yielding any results.

Comment: Can you post the "BasicHttpBinding_ICandidateManagementService" portion of the config?

Comment: Thanks for the help Rich... I did eventually solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your client endpoint:

Shouldn't the bindingConfiguration be

```
bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_ICandidateManagementService"
```

Instead of

```
bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IAdminService"
```

Comment: That's just a typo error in the question, I am using the correct config.

Comment: Are you streaming or buffering for your transfer mode(are your parameters/response stream type)?  According to your configs, you are doing buffered on service, but streaming on client. I think that they both have to be the same on each end otherwise how it is it going to know how to chunk it accordingly?  Have you/can you try making them the same and giving it another shot to see if that works?

Comment: I checked it, am using buffered at both server and client. As there is no concept of streaming in my implementation.