# WCF service returning 404 on method requests

Tags: c#, wcf, ssl, iis-7.5

I have a WCF service page running only WebGets/WebInvokes over SSL - it works fine on my local machine (self signed cert). On production, however, I can reach service.svc (and it gives me the message about how to consume) but service.svc/AnyRequest returns a 404. Both environments are hosted in IIS 7.5.

I've enabled tracing and the service isn't even picking up any of the method requests (e.g. service.svc/SomeRequest), however it is processing `service.svc` just fine. It's also listening at `https://computername.domain.net/path/service.svc` - is this normal? Should it normally be pointing to `https://publicfacing.com/path/service.svc`?

Also note that the production server is hosting multiple sites within IIS.

Below is the system.serviceModel section of my web.config. The SSLBehave was suggested from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/470111).

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="TransportSecurity">
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None"></transport>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="SSLBehave">
          <useRequestHeadersForMetadataAddress>
            <defaultPorts>
              <add scheme="https" port="443"/>
            </defaultPorts>
          </useRequestHeadersForMetadataAddress>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="UserManagement.ajaxAspNetAjaxBehavior">
          <webHttp defaultOutgoingResponseFormat="Json" defaultBodyStyle="Wrapped" />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"
      multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    <services>
      <service name="UserManagement.ajax" behaviorConfiguration="SSLBehave">
        <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="UserManagement.ajaxAspNetAjaxBehavior"
          binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="TransportSecurity" contract="UserManagement.ajax" />
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: does the service work if invoked locally?

Comment: @theusguy Negative, still returning 404.

Comment: If your problem still exists, my answer maybe help you

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I would start by checking a number of things;

- Permissions on the hosted directory?
- .Net version is correct?
- Have you added the certificate to the site?
- Try putting an image in the same path, can you navigate to that (rule out the odd occasional path mappings)

Good luck!

Comment: Though this did not solve my issue, most of these are the best bet for anyone searching for a solution. Enjoy the bounty. :)

Comment: ElatedOwl, if you solved the problem, please post your answer.

Comment: To anyone finding this, I had a similar problem, here's my question, complete with the **solution**: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26398049

Answer (score 30):

The first thing I do whenever I hit a 404 with a newly-developed WCF Web Service is checking the handler mapping required to interpret this type of call, because it's often the cause of the issue. There are several ways to work around the problem, many of which require a manual execution of the `ServiceModelReg.exe` console command: these are undoubtedly valid procedures but might also not work – or create additional problems – if your development machine has a particularly complex configuration. The resolution method I propose below is slightly longer to pull off, but has the advantage of solving the problem more safely and securely.

- Open the **Server Manager** interface for machine management, usually present in both the *Task Bar* and the *Start menu*.
- Go to the *Dashboard (or Control Panel)* and select **Add Role or Feature** to open the Wizard.
- Select the **Role-based or Feature-based installation type** and the server you want to work on, that is, your local / local server.
- Go to the **Features** section: Once there, expand the **.NET Framework 3.5 Features** node and / or the **.NET Framework 4.5 Features** node, depending on what you have installed: if you have both, you should perform the following step twice (for each one of them).
- Expand the WCF Services section (if available), then select **HTTP Activation** (see screenshot below).
- Continue until you complete the Wizard, then click **Install**.

[image]

Once the installation is complete, you should be able to run your WCF Service without incurring in the 404 error ever again.

For additional info regarding this specific issue and how to fix it, you can also [read this post](http://www.ryadel.com/en/wcf-web-service-windows-server-2012-iis-8-404-error-fix/) on my blog.

Comment: Super helpful. I was tired of exploring everything just to find WCF http activation was disabled. Thanks a ton!!

Comment: On Windows 10 I enabled this option by going to: Control Panel > Programs > Turn Windows features on or off > .NET Framework 4.7 Advanced Services > WCF Services > HTTP Activation

Comment: Wanted to share that I was migrating some `WCF` services from an old server to a new `Windows Server 2019` server and this fixed the issue. Before this I was getting error `HTTP Error 404.0` when calling the WCF.

Answer (score 7):

You can implement transport level security using WsHttp bindings. See [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36705/7-simple-steps-to-enable-HTTPS-on-WCF-WsHttp-bindi); in your bindings try this biding instead:

```
<wsHttpBinding>
<binding name="TransportSecurity">
<security mode="Transport">
<transport clientCredentialType="None"/>
</security>
</binding>
</wsHttpBinding>
```

The article mentions you should tie up the bindings with the end points.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem.  From what I read, WCF isnt NT Authenticated authorization (or HTTPContext compatible) by default.

I had to add this to my config file for the WCF service web.config in the  section:

```
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"/>
```

Which you did, plus this:

And on the actual service class definiation I had to add:

```
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
public class DataService : IDataDeliveryServiceContract
```

This fixed my problem.

Comment: hey i added tag in WCF.config file and attribute too in the service as u told but still when i am getting error and cross browsing error.

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps in your RouteConfig.cs file add this line:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.svc/{*pathInfo}");
```

So long as your .svc file is in the root of the application.

Comment: This answer is very helpful when you try to call the `WCF Service` straight away from MVC App. I was getting `404 - Not Found error` for jquery post request. Now resolved, this helped me. :)

Answer (score 4):

As you mentioned you can access your service by .svc extension `service.svc` but not in REST format `service.svc/AnyRequest`, the problem must be in [routing integration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee358760.aspx).

add this to your `web.config`

```
 <system.webServer>
  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
    <add name="UrlRoutingModule" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
  </modules>
  <handlers>
    <add name="UrlRoutingHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="*" path="UrlRouting.axd"/>
  </handlers>
 </system.webServer>
```

In the IIS 6 The cause of this error must be `Check that file exists` setting of svc extention, make sure "Check that file exists is unchecked". For more information see [IIS Hosted Service Fails](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752252%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

To help others that find themselves stuck with this - It may be that your service name is not the [fully qualified name](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2585295), which it must be.

Answer (score 1):

The following setting in web.config fixed a WCF .svc 404 on a HTTPS web site :

```
      <webHttpBinding>
             <!-- https -->
             <security mode="Transport">
                    <transport clientCredentialType = "None" proxyCredentialType="None"/>
            </security>
    </binding>
  </webHttpBinding>
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried the above solutions, installing WCF Services, ensuring that there were proper permissions in the API directory and several other things.

While some of those were issues there was one issue for me that isn't mentioned above.

If Request Filtering is enabled for the entire server or the given site, make sure that .svc is a trusted file name extension, otherwise it will be blocked.  Go to IIS > Request Filtering.  Click on Edit Feature Settings.  Check to see if "allow unlisted file extensions" is checked.  If so, make sure that there is an entry in the list for .svc.  Otherwise IIS will block the file from being served.